# Many instances of javaw.exe

Tags: java, swing

Task Manager shows many instances of javaw.exe residing in memory making windows run out of memory. I'm using this code to close my java application:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() 
{
    public void run()
    {
       Form1 frame = new Form1();
       frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
});
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Problem solved: I've moved the following lines from the JFrame constructor to the main function: frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(900,800));
frame.setLocation (0, 10);
frame.setVisible(true);

Answer (score 1):

Use [ProcessExplorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) instead of TaskManager.
Select one of the javaw.exe processes, go to the image tab, and you will be able to see the full command line.
This will help you to determine what the javaw.exe processes actually are.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly ensure %JAVA_HOME%/bin is set in your PATH and %JAVA_HOME% is pointed to your JDK.

Then to leverage these JDK tools,

use jps -l to list all the java processes.

use `jstack -l <pid>` to check the stack trace and you can find some clues.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
     public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we){
        System.exit(0);
     }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Then no idea.. but this is very strange. Try without SwingWorker.. or it is EDT?